# Selecting with Indexing is an anti-pattern in Polars: How to parse and transform (select/filter?) a CSV that seems to require so?

Tags: csv, rust, python-polars, rust-polars, oscilloscope

I would like to read the following (quite broken, IMO) CSV with Pola-rs, coming from a Rigol MSO5000 oscilloscope:

```
D7-D0,D15-D8,t0 = -25.01s, tInc = 2e-06,
+2.470000E+02,2.000000E+00,,
+1.590000E+02,1.600000E+01,,
+2.400000E+02,2.000000E+00,,
+2.470000E+02,+1.300000E+02,,
+1.590000E+02,1.800000E+01,,
+2.470000E+02,+1.300000E+02,,
9.500000E+01,1.800000E+01,,
9.500000E+01,1.800000E+01,,
+2.400000E+02,0.000000E+00,,
(...)
```

Here's my current Jupyter Notebook iteration/attempt before finding out that [Selecting with indexing is discouraged in Pola-rs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/selecting_data/selecting_data_indexing.html#selecting-with-indexing):

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.read_csv("normal0.csv")

# Grab initial condition and increments
t0 = df.columns[2]; assert "t0" in t0; t0 = float(t0.split('=')[1].replace('s', '').strip())
tinc = df.columns[3]; assert "tInc" in tinc; tinc = float(tinc.split('=')[1].strip())

# TODO: Generate Series() from t0+tinc and include it in the final DataFrame

# Reshape and cleanup
probes = df.with_column(df["D7-D0"].cast(pl.Float32).alias("D0-D7 floats")) \
             .with_column(df["D15-D8"].cast(pl.Float32).alias("D15-D8 floats")) \
             .drop(df.columns[2]) \
             .drop(df.columns[3])
(...)

def split_probes(probes: pl.Series):
    ''' Splits bundles of probe cables such as D0-D7 or D15-D8 into individual dataframe columns
    '''
    out = pl.DataFrame(columns=["D"+str(line) for line in range(0,16)])
#    for row in range(probes.height):
#        for probe in range(0, 7):
#            out["D"+str(probe)].with_columns(probes["D0-D7 floats"][row % (probe + 1)])
#         for probe in reversed(range(9, 16)): # TODO: Fix future captures or parametrise this
#             outprobes["D15-D8 floats"][row % probe]
```

And here's my lower-level CSV parsing Rust pseudocode approach when [I was told on Polars Discord that this problem might not be optimally solvable with dataframe libraries](https://discord.com/channels/908022250106667068/911186243465904178/1053978136951398430):

```rust
use csv;
use std::error::Error;
use std::io;
use std::process;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct OrigOscilloscope {
    #[serde(rename = "D7-D0")]
    d7_d0: String, // TODO: Unfortunately those fields are "user-flippable" in order from the scope, i.e: d0_d7 vs d7_d0
    #[serde(rename = "D15-D8")]
    d15_d8: String,
    // Do not even register those on Serde as they are empty rows anyway
    // t0: Option<String>,
    // t_inc: Option<String>
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct LAProbesOscilloscopeState {
    //Vec<d0...d15>: Vec<Vec<16*f32>>, // TODO: More appropriate struct representation for the target dataframe
    d0: f32,
    d1: f32,
    d2: f32,
    d3: f32,
    d4: f32,
    d5: f32,
    d6: f32,
    d7: f32,
    d8: f32,
    d9: f32,
    d10: f32,
    d11: f32,
    d12: f32,
    d13: f32,
    d14: f32,
    d15: f32,
    timestamp: f32
}

fn run() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(false)
        .flexible(true) // ignore broken header
        .from_reader(io::stdin());

    // Get timeseries information from header... :facepalm: rigol
    // Initial timestamp...
    let header = rdr.headers()?.clone();
    let t0_header: Vec<&str> = header[2].split('=').collect();
    let t0 = t0_header[1].trim_start().replace('s', "").parse::<f32>()?;
    // ...and increments
    let tinc_header: Vec<&str> = header[3].split('=').collect();
    let tinc = tinc_header[1].trim_start().parse::<f32>()?;
    println!("Initial timestamp {t0} with increments of {tinc} seconds");

    // Now do the splitting of wires from its Dx-Dy "bundles"
    let mut timestamp = t0;
    for result in rdr.deserialize().skip(1) {
        let row: OrigOscilloscope = result?;

        // if rdr.position().line().rem_euclid(8) {
        // // Read D0-D15 field(s), expanding them into the current row, matching its column
        // }
        // println!("{:#?}", row.d7_d0.parse::<f32>()?);

        // update timestamp for this row
        timestamp = timestamp + tinc;
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = run() {
        println!("{}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

I hope that it's clear that the target dataframe desired would look like this:

```
d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10, d11, d12, d13, d14, d15, timestamp
95, 95, 247, 159, 247, 240, 159, 247 (...)                            -25.01+000000.2
(...)
```

And the resulting code should (ideally?) be using Polars efficiently. Also, as mentioned above, avoiding "Selecting with Indexing" since it might be completely deprecated in the future in Polars.

Comment: You can use [`pl.col("D7-D0")`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/notebooks/introduction_polars-py.html?highlight=col()#selection-context) to select columns. Does the Python code generate the correct output?

Comment: Ok, that'd select the entire column... and then?

Can you elaborate on how to splice D0-D7 and D8-D15 into rows of 16 columns (plus timestamp on each of those new rows) without using Select with Indexing?

Comment: Does the Python code currently do what you want? Or do you need help finishing the `split_probes()` function? The deprecated syntax is just the square brackets:`df["D7-D0"]` - you can replace those with `pl.col("...")` - the code will still work the same.

Comment: No, it doesn't do what I want, I'd need help finishing the split_probes() function and also attaching a (generated) timeseries to it all.

Comment: How does your desired output look?

Comment: @ritchie46 There's the desired output at the end of the post, let me know if it's not clear, happy to edit/elaborate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `unstack` (which is incredibly performant).

Let's start with this data (which simply replicates values that you provided).  I've also changed the column names, just to make things easier to inspect:

```py
import polars as pl
from io import StringIO

normal_csv = """D7-D0,D15-D8,t0 = -25.01s, tInc = 2e-06,
+2.470000E+02,2.000000E+00,,
+1.590000E+02,1.600000E+01,,
+2.400000E+02,2.000000E+00,,
+2.470000E+02,+1.300000E+02,,
+1.590000E+02,1.800000E+01,,
+2.470000E+02,+1.300000E+02,,
9.500000E+01,1.800000E+01,,
9.500000E+01,1.800000E+01,,
+2.470000E+02,2.000000E+00,,
+1.590000E+02,1.600000E+01,,
+2.400000E+02,2.000000E+00,,
+2.470000E+02,+1.300000E+02,,
+1.590000E+02,1.800000E+01,,
+2.470000E+02,+1.300000E+02,,
9.500000E+01,1.800000E+01,,
9.500000E+01,1.800000E+01,,"""


df = pl.read_csv(file=StringIO(normal_csv),
                 new_columns=('D', 'E', 't0', 'tInc'))
df
```

```
shape: (16, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬──────┬──────┐
│ D     ┆ E     ┆ t0   ┆ tInc │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞═══════╪═══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 247.0 ┆ 2.0   ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 159.0 ┆ 16.0  ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 240.0 ┆ 2.0   ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 247.0 ┆ 130.0 ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 159.0 ┆ 18.0  ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 247.0 ┆ 130.0 ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 95.0  ┆ 18.0  ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 95.0  ┆ 18.0  ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 247.0 ┆ 2.0   ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 159.0 ┆ 16.0  ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 240.0 ┆ 2.0   ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 247.0 ┆ 130.0 ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 159.0 ┆ 18.0  ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 247.0 ┆ 130.0 ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 95.0  ┆ 18.0  ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 95.0  ┆ 18.0  ┆ null ┆ null │
└───────┴───────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Since I'm not familiar with your data source, I'm going to assume that your input data has a regularized pattern -- specifically that D7-D0 are always provided (i.e., no skipped lines in the csv file).

If so, here's some highly performant code that should get the ball rolling...

```py
(
    df
    .reverse()
    .unstack(step=8,
             how='horizontal',
             columns=('D', 'E'),
             )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 16)
┌──────┬──────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬──────┬───────┬─────┬──────┬─────┐
│ D_0  ┆ D_1  ┆ D_2   ┆ D_3   ┆ D_4   ┆ D_5   ┆ D_6   ┆ D_7   ┆ E_0  ┆ E_1  ┆ E_2   ┆ E_3  ┆ E_4   ┆ E_5 ┆ E_6  ┆ E_7 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64   ┆ f64  ┆ f64   ┆ f64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64 │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════╪══════╪═══════╪══════╪═══════╪═════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 95.0 ┆ 95.0 ┆ 247.0 ┆ 159.0 ┆ 247.0 ┆ 240.0 ┆ 159.0 ┆ 247.0 ┆ 18.0 ┆ 18.0 ┆ 130.0 ┆ 18.0 ┆ 130.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 16.0 ┆ 2.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 95.0 ┆ 95.0 ┆ 247.0 ┆ 159.0 ┆ 247.0 ┆ 240.0 ┆ 159.0 ┆ 247.0 ┆ 18.0 ┆ 18.0 ┆ 130.0 ┆ 18.0 ┆ 130.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 16.0 ┆ 2.0 │
└──────┴──────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴──────┴───────┴─────┴──────┴─────┘
```

This doesn't have your desired column names (which you can change).  Nor does it contain the timing information.  But it may help you get started in the right direction.